# Excel for Mac does not offer "Save as" for CSV format?

Tags: ms-office

According to documentation I can find the "Save as" should allow selecting *csv* and other types: But maybe this is only for non-MacOS versions of Excel?  [Save an Excel Spreadsheet as csv](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/6409-saving-an-excel-file-as-a-csv-file?lang=en_US)

But when attempting to save I only see variants of Excel:

[image]

So how to save to CSV?

I am using *Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.52*

[image]

[image]

File formats: as mentioned there are only .xls* offered.

[image]

Comment: Where are you looking? What does the File Formats show?

Comment: @mmmmmm added screenshot showing that only .xls* formats are shown

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that makes it way easier to understand. Did you check in Excel‘s preferences whether an option would influence that?

Comment: Also, are you saving locally or to an online location?

Comment: @nohillside  I am saving locally

Comment: Or is your Mac or your Office license part of an enterprise account?

Comment: It's 100% personal mac / personal office license

Answer (score 3):

I would click on File Format and select from there (on a macbook pro 15"):

[image]

Comment: I added screenshots to the OP : none of those non-XLS options show up for me. That's the whoel reason for  the question. I did mention that but apparently the screenshots are needed to be clear.

Answer (score -2):

You can save the file to your computers, such as a hard drive or flash drive, or a web service, such as OneDrive. You can also export files in different formats and save them under different names. I had a similar situation, and only it took me less time to create the document because I worked with a program I downloaded from https://www.wallstreetoasis.com/resources/excel/study/index-match-formula-excel. It makes working with Excel easy. So when you save a file, you can usually change its name, storage location, and format, if necessary. However, you may not need to change all of these at once.

Comment: How do you save as a .csv file - this is the question that is asked?